# Error in opening the compiled module file. Check INCLUDE paths. [HDF5]

Tags: bash, fortran, hdf5

I'm trying to compile the fortran code and getting the following error

```
    sd_io_v005_basics.f90(6): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [HDF5]
  use hdf5
    sd_io_v005_basics.f90(7): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [PARIO]
  use pario
```

I have tried

```
module load LIBRARIES
module load hdf5
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

I'm still getting the same error. How do I specify the path of these modules?

Comment: How do you compile your code? Which exact commands do you use? Use the `-I` flag or the equivalent in your compiler's manual. We probably have a duplicate.

Comment: I'm using make to compile the code.

Comment: That does not matter at all. Which command does the `make` create for you? Use the flag I suggested. You must tell the compiler where `hdf5.mod` is.

Comment: When using modules, do not try to short-circuit it via `~/.bashrh`, other environment variables might have been defined. To know what make is doing, try running `make -n` (this will not execute anything, just print the commands that would be executed. You may also read the Makefile :-)